# Enable Button via jQuery not working

Tags: jquery

I want to check two input fields if the password matches. I'm more or less successful meaning that I'm able to disable the button but when the passwords match, the button won't enable again. Do you know why this is the case in the following code? Thank you!

```js
$('#password, #cfmPassword').on('keyup', function () {
  if ($('#password').val() == $('#cfmPassword').val()) {
    $('#message').html('Match').css('color', 'green');
    //$('#submitButton').removeAttr('disabled');    // <--- Not working
    $('#submitButton').prop("disabled", false); // <--- Not working
  } else 
    $('#message').html('No Match').css('color', 'red');
   //$('#submitButton').attr('disabled','disabled');
    $('#submitButton').prop("disabled", true); // <--- Works!
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="password">PW:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="" required>
<br />
<label for="cfmPassword">Confirm:</label>
<input type="password" name="cfmPassword" id="cfmPassword" placeholder="" required>
<span id='message'></span>   
<br />
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitButton" value="Save">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing curly brackets around your else statement.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing { and } of else part.so that every time what ever the condition is the button will be disabled.